# React Native Project not able to run

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I am new in **React Native**  and trying to run the project for the first time. Whenever I try to run it it shows the error at the cmd console as

[image: this is showing this error]

I also **tried uninstalling the previous version of node and installed it again** and it still shows the same problem. **checked out some of the solutions** and didn't work.

I'm using node and npm as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Did you clone this project from somewhere else? If you did, you might have forgotten to install dependencies. Try running `npm install` first, then run `npm start`.

Comment: No I created the project myself.

Comment: I am not able to figure out why even I am getting this error ?

Comment: These errors can be frustrating at times. I would attempt to re-create the project in a separate folder. Add the necessary dependencies and test the project. You might find that adding a particular dependency breaks the project.

Comment: @JuanMarco same error again and again , even creating the project in the different drive. I think project has to do with something path issue or some node issue. If you think so , please let me know. Really frustrating error.

Comment: what is the version of your react-scripts?

Comment: Problem solved , after adding path to set path variable under system variable , edit , and add C:\Windows\System32\

Answer (score 0):

try installing you node_modules after removing the old ones:
I suggest doing these three steps:

1- `npm install -g npm@latest` to update npm because it is sometimes buggy.

2- `rm -rf node_modules/` to remove the existing modules.

3- `npm install` to re-install the project dependencies.

Comment: Run command 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' in your android sdk platform tools folder.